# slow down plymouth animated theme

Tags: 20.04, plymouth

I am attempting to make a (initially very simple) custom animated plymouth theme in ubuntu 20.04.  It's a very simple theme that really revolves around 2 images.  Like a blinking cursor.

The refresh_callback function used to run the animation is too fast. I've tried adjusting

```
fun refresh_callback ()
  {
    flyingman_sprite.SetImage(flyingman_image[Math.Int(progress / 3) % 2 ]);
    progress++;
  }
  
Plymouth.SetRefreshFunction (refresh_callback);
```

I'm new to plymouth themes, and am probably missing something.  I can add multiple images of the "ON" and "OFF" states of the animation to essentially render the same image longer before switching to the other image, but that seems wrong.  What would be a better way to slow the image change down?